# Is it true that if $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in int(A)$ then $\exists s > 0 \mid d(x,y) \ge \varepsilon + s,\;\forall y \not\in A^\varepsilon$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ be a nonempty subset of $X$ with interior $\overset{\circ}{A}$, closure $\overline{A}$, and boundary $\partial A$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, define $\varepsilon$-enlargement of $A$ by $A^\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) \le \varepsilon\}$, where $d(x,A) := \inf_{a \in A} d(x,a)$. Note that $\overline{A} = \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) = 0\}$.

Observe that if $x \in \overline{A}$ and $y \in X\setminus A^\varepsilon$, then $\varepsilon < d(y, A) \le d(x, y) + d(x,A) = d(x,y) + 0$, i.e
$$
d(x,y) > \varepsilon. \tag{1}
$$

One would hope that if $x$ is an interior point of $A$, then the RHS of the bound (1) can be increased.

> **Question.** Is it true that if $x \in \overset{\circ}{A}$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x,y) > \varepsilon + \delta$ for every $y \in X\setminus A^\varepsilon$ ?

## Affirmative answer for normed inner-product vector space

Suppose $X=(X,d)$ is a normed inner-product vector space. Because $x \in \overset{\circ}{A}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\{x' \in X \mid d(x',x) < \delta\} \subseteq A$. It is clear that $d(x,\partial A) \ge \delta$. Let $z$ be a point of intersection between $\overline{A}$ and the coord $[x,y]$. Note that we must have $z \in \partial A$ and $d(z,y) > \varepsilon$. By positive collinearity of $x-z$ and $z-y$, we compute
$$d(x,y) = d(y,z) + d(z,x) > \varepsilon + d(z,x) \ge \varepsilon + d(x,\partial A) \ge \varepsilon + \delta.
$$
Thus $d(x,y) > \varepsilon + \delta$.

This motivates the following relaxed question.

> **Question 2.** In case the above question can not be answered affirmatively in general, minimal assumptions can be made about $X$ to alleviate this ?

## Edit

- It has been observed in the comments that the question doesn't have an affirmative answer in general (example: $X = (-\infty,-1] \cup \{0\} \cup [1,+\infty)$, $A=\{0\}$, $x=0$, $\varepsilon=1$, and $y=-1$). I've noted that all counterexamples seem to be somewhat "pathological". So I'm wondering
- In case $(X,d)$ is a space with the "mid-point property", I've answered the question in the affirmative. See answer below. Such spaces include: normed vector spaces (already proved here), and general *complete geodesic spaces*.

> **Question 3.** Is there would some general condition (beyond the normed vector-space example) on the space $X$ which would ensure that the question is answered in the affirmative ?

Comment: Easy counterexample: $X:= (-\infty, -1] \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup [1, \infty)$ with the restriction of the standard metric, $A:= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (meaning $\overline{A}=\overset{\circ}A$), $\epsilon =1$.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I've noted that all counterexamples seem to be somewhat "pathological". So I'm wondering whether there would some general condition (beyond the normed vector-space example) on the space $X$ which would ensure that the question is answered in the affirmative. See edited question.

Comment: For example, it seems if $X$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R$, then the answer is: **Yes**. However, maybe in higher dimensions, connectedness (though quite restrictive) may not be sufficient. Just thinking out loud...

Comment: Seems like length metric spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) might do. Connectedness is not enough though. Take $X= \mathbb R^2 \setminus (0,1)^2$, $A=(-\infty, 0] \times \mathbb R$, $\epsilon=1$, $x=(0,1/2)$.

Comment: Indeed I was skeptical about higher dimensions, though I think it should be true for subspaces of $\mathbb R$. Thanks for the 2D counterexample. Below, I've been able give a solution for spaces with the "mid-point property". I've not yet tried with length spaces (for complete spaces, being a length space is equivalent to being a space with almost mid-points). I'd appreciate if you took a look at my (partial) solution below and tell me what you think. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your understanding of the problem is correct. There was a mis-type in my answer which took the sense out of it. Fixed.

Comment: Here is another counterexample from a different area: Let $K$ be a non-archimedean field whose value group $\lvert K^\times \rvert$ is dense (e.g. an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$, or a completion thereof), and $X$ any finite-dim. vector space over $K$ with the standard maximum norm (which induces the metric). Then for any $x \in X$, $r \in \lvert K^\times \rvert$, take $A = B(x,r)$ and $\epsilon = r$. By the strict triangle inequality, the complement of  $A=A_\epsilon$ consists of all $y$ with $d(x,y) > \epsilon$, which by density of the value group come arbitrarily close to $\epsilon$.

Comment: Holy s****. That's so beautiful. Is it a coincidence that (non)archimedeanness seems to play an important role ? Indeed, i used the fact that $\mathbb R$ is archimedean to construct my proof for the case of "mid-point" spaces.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution for spaces with the "mid-point property"

**Disclaimer:** *Sorry for answering my own question, but the post below would be too long as a comment or edit to the question.*

Let $(X, d)$ have the **mid-point property**. This means that for every $x,y \in X$ there exists $z \in X$ (called the mid-point of $x$ and $y$) such that $d(x,z) = d(z, y) = d(x,y)/2$. Spaces with the mid-point property include *complete geodesic spaces* (see [Lemma 2.2](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~lang/LengthSpaces.pdf)), etc.

---

Now, now let $x \in int(A)$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
\overset{\circ}{B}(x;\delta) \subseteq A, \tag{*}
$$
where $\overset{\circ}{B}(x;\delta) := \{z \in \mathcal X \mid d(z,x) < \delta\}$.

> ***Claim.*** $d(x,y) > \varepsilon + \delta/2\;\forall y \in X\setminus A^\varepsilon$.

***Proof.*** Let $y \in X\setminus A^\varepsilon$. Set $z_0 := y$, and recursively, for each $k\in \mathbb N$, define $z_{k+1}$ to be the mid-point of $x$ and $z_{k}$. It's easy to see that
$$
d(x,z_k) = 2^{-k}d(x,y) \text{ and }d(x,y) = d(x,z_k) + d(z_k,z_{k-1}) + \ldots + d(z_1,y).
$$
So, by triangle inequality, it holds that

$$
d(x,y) \ge d(x,z_k)+d(z_k,y)\;\forall k \ge 1. \tag{2}
$$

Let $k^* \ge 1$ be the smallest $k$ such that $2^{-k^*}d(x,y) < \delta$ (exists by Archimedian property + well-ordering principle).
Then $d(x,z_{k^*}) = 2^{-k^*}d(x,y) < \delta$, i.e $z_{k^*} \in \overset{\circ}{B}(x;\delta)$. I claim that

$$
d(x,z_{k^*}) \ge \delta/2. \tag{3}
$$

Otherwise, $2^{-(k^*-1)}d(x,y)= 2d(x,z_{k^*}) < \delta$, contradicting the minimality of $k^*$.

Now, by *(2)* and *(3)*, we have $d(x, y) \ge d(x,z_{k^*}) + d(z_{k^*},y) \ge \delta/2 + d(z_{k^*},y)$. Because $z_{k^*} \in \overset{\circ}B(x;\delta) \subseteq A$ by *(1)*, and $d(y,A) > \varepsilon$ since $y \in X\setminus A^\varepsilon$, it holds that $d(z_{k^*},y) \ge d(A,y) > \varepsilon$. Therefore $d(x,y) > \varepsilon + \delta / 2$. $\quad\quad\quad\Box$