# Conditions for a certain set to be closed in product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal U := (U_x)_{x \in X}$ be a system of closed subsets of $X$ such that $x \in U_x$ for all $x \in X$. Define $\Omega := \{(x,x') \in X^2 \mid U_x \cap U_{x'} \ne \emptyset\}$.

> **Question.** Under what conditions on $\mathcal U$ is $\Omega$ closed in the product topology on $X^2$ ?

## Example: closed balls in metric space

Let $X=(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\varepsilon > 0$. For each $x \in X$, let $U_x$ be the closed ball around $x$ of radius $\varepsilon$. Then one computes $\Omega = \{(x,x') \in X^2 \mid d(x',x) \le 2\varepsilon\}$, which is closed.

Comment: In your example the situation is more tricky. If $U_x\cap U_{x’}\ne\emptyset$ then there exists a point $x’’\in U_x\cap U_{x’}$, so $d(x,x’)\le d(x,x’’)+d(x’’,x)\le 2\varepsilon$. But if $d(x,x’)\le 2\varepsilon $ then a point $x’’\in U_x\cap U_{x’}$ does not necessary exist. On the other hand, it exists provided  
$(X,d)$ has the [mid-point property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486888/is-it-true-that-if-varepsilon-0-and-x-in-inta-then-exists-s-0-mid/3490882#3490882).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the insight. It's beginning to look like the"mid-point property" is a sufficient condition that removes many nasty complications I've had recently in certain problems on metric spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a map such that $F(x)=U_x$ for each $x\in X$. The closedness of $\Omega$ is equivalent to the following condition. If $x,x’\in X$ and $F(x)\cap F(x’)=\emptyset$ then there exist neighborhood $O_x$ of $x$ and $O_{x’}$ of $x’$ such that $F(y)\cap F(y’)=\emptyset$ for each $y\in O_x$ and $y’\in O_{x’}$. This holds provided the space is normal and the map $F$ is upper semicontinuous. The latter means that for each open subset $U$ of $x$ the set $\{x: F(x)\subset U\}$ is open. The following exercise from Engelking’s “General topology” describes basic properties of upper semicontinuous maps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alex once again for another instructive answer.